# Default Routing with multiple parameters is loading component

Tags: angular, routes

Default rout is not loading Tab Component be default . it only works if I replace the below code

{
                path: 'tab/:id', 
                component: TabComponent  tabs
            }// note:works with one parameter only
app.routing.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    {
        path: '',
        component: NavMenuComponent, // nav component
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'tab/' ,
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'tab/:id/:title', 
                component: TabComponent // tabs
            }
        ]
    },

];
```

manu.copnent.html

```
 <ul class="list-unstyled list" *ngFor='let tab of tabs'>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/tab',tab.LinkTabID,tab.TabName]" class="anchorLink"><i class="icon-home scolor"></i><font color="white">{{tab.TabName}}</font></a></li>



        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't navigate to a non-existing route, and the route `tab/` doesn't exist, only `tab/1/foo` (or whatever values you use for the parameters).

If you want to be able to navigate to `tab/` you need to create such a route

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    {
        path: '',
        component: NavMenuComponent, // nav component
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/tab' ,
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'tab', 
                component: TabComponent // tabs
            }
            {
                path: 'tab/:id/:title', 
                component: TabComponent // tabs
            }
        ]
    },

];
```

You should be aware that navigating from `tabs/` to `tabs/1/foo` `TabComponent` is destroyed and recreated while navigating from 
`tabs/1/foo` to `tabs/2/bar` `TabComponent` is reused.

Comment: still the same issue,Default rout is not loading Tab Component (it does not even hit the constructor). it only works when I click on a menu item.

Comment: Try `redirectTo: '/tab'` with a leading `/` like in my updated answer, otherwise it's trying to navigate to a child of the `''` route.

Comment: tried this with no luck:  {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/tab/',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in Plunker? Plunker has a ready-to-use Angular2 template.